# Finding Hard Coded (Magic) numbers and Strings

Tags: java, sonarqube, static-analysis, magic-numbers

Is there a way to find all hard coded numbers and strings in Java?
I mean values which have not been placed into dedicated variables.

For example :

```
while (i < 6) {
    System.out.println("6 is a number"); // Hard Coded, "Magic" String
}
```

I got suggestions on SonarQube but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Do you mean "`static`" when you say "`hard coded`"?

Comment: basically anything that could be stored in terms of a variable but was just inserted in a block of code. For example, 6 could be initialized as a variable so it will be easier to change later. I just want a way to check inside a block of code for these kinds of bad coding practices

Comment: Why all the downotes? This is a legitimate, well formatted and interesting question. Please remove the downvote if you can not explain why you did so.

Answer (score 5):

SonarJava, the Java plugin for SonarQube, has a rule explicitly targeting magic numbers. See its description here: [S109 - Magic numbers should not be used](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules?open=squid%3AS109&rule_key=squid%3AS109).

There is also a rule which is going to ask you to define constants instead of using multiple time the same string, but only when used in the same file (like already mentioned in the other answer) ([S1192 - String literals should not be duplicated](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules?open=squid%3AS1192&rule_key=squid%3AS1192)). Consequently, it is not going to flag any string constant used only once in the body of any methods, nor identify duplicated constants spread across multiple files.

If you desperately need to track usage of **all** the string constants in your project(s), the best way would be to write your own rule targeting them, as part of a custom plugin (See [Writing Custom Java Rules](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101)).

Now, if you want to benefit from these rules, the only thing you have to do is to setup the analysis of your project in order to perform a SonarQube analysis of your code, and be sure that all the rules you need are enabled, as they are not all part of default quality profile (See [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/), or [SonarCloud](https://about.sonarcloud.io/) websites for details about setup).

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube/SonarLint has dedicated issues regarding repetitive usage of the same HC strings, however this is done in the scope of a single class file.

This means that if you are using the same HC String only once or twice in each class file, but you have 10 such files, then SQ/SL will not detected this issue and you will be unaware of the HC/Magic String issue.

I suggest you try to use your IDE's searching capabilities with a little bit of automation - build a simple text list of suspected magic strings and use it as an input to your IDE's searching tool, so it will go over your entire work-space and mark/sum up all magic string usages in your project.

There is support for detecting magic numbers in SQ/SL - the `Magic numbers should not be used` rule. Same detection issues as stated above for magic strings.

Note - the solution I tend to use for HC magic Strings/ints is a Constants utility class, with `public static final` variables. In order to enhance usage I allow the HC strings to optionally contain tags which can be parsed out with dynamic values ("My [tag] String" -[tag = nice]--> "My nice String").